# What does Cortana's "Give me flight updates only" option do?

Tags: cortana, 8.1-update-1

When Cortana asks if I want to track a flight as a trip, she gives the option to "Give me flight updates only" as an alternative to choosing yes. However, as far as I can tell, the way she saves trips to her notebook is identical regardless of the option I choose (in that I still get a trip planner in interests even after opting for flight updates only). How is this feature supposed to work?